# Terminal acts weired while downloading some software

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, downloads

[image]

This is what happens when i try to download some software via the terminal. I dont see any particular command that i would have issued that caused this. It is a fresh installed, and i have inly tweaked some compiz settings, that too after terminal started behaving like this. I am running on ubuntu 14.04.3 64 bit.

Comment: I dont see an image..

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the  progress bar.

Why it is giving you a step by step install progress is beyond me unless you are hitting enter during the update/install.

You can check for package error, install a new progress bar,or try reinstall the terminal. I would recommend enabling Progress Fancy this should fix the issue and has a great progress bar.

Enable it by using:

```
echo 'Dpkg::Progress-Fancy "1";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99progressbar
```